# how to start process in background/Terminated iOS apps

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I want to start some process in background mode on timer event.i want to know that is it possible to get start any process in background or terminated apps on timer event,if i set timer for Five minuets and close the app not even running in background mode than after five min process should start automatically, is it possible in iOS?

Comment: Please read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am able to process in background but i want to start process in background on just timer event? is it possible?

Comment: Short answer, no, it is not possible

Answer (score 4):

- I have read my Documents and also tried out this Scenario, I have concluded that Apple doesn't provide any background Process while app is terminated excluding Push Notification.
- If you want to run any background process then app must be active in background.

Comment: "while app is terminated excluding Push Notification.". I presume you mean silent push, however if the user has terminated the app a silent push is not sent to the app in that situation.

Comment: Further to @Gruntcakes comment, there are scenarios where iOS will re-launch your terminated app including background location mode with significant location change active, background Bluetooth central and background iBeacon/geofence regions.  None of these are likely to be useful to the OP though.

Comment: "I presume you mean silent push" Ya I am talking about Silent Push. No, Silent Push working in the case of App Terminate.